# Push array value based on array index in loop

Tags: php

I wanna push array based on its index inside loop. But `$q[$i]` detected as string. How to solve it?

```
$smallPhrase = array(35) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "terima kasih"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "40"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "kemudian"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "20"
  } ... 
}
$q = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($smallPhrase); $i++) {
      array_push($q[$i], $smallPhrase[$i][0],$smallPhrase[$i][1]);
    }
```

expected result =

```
    $q[0] = $smallPhrase[0][0],$smallPhrase[0][1];
    $q[1] = $smallPhrase[1][0],$smallPhrase[1][1];
    $q[2] = $smallPhrase[2][0],$smallPhrase[2][1];
```

This `$smallPhrase` is under loop also, so in next loop data will be replaced but the structure keep the same.

I just want to push `$smallPhrase` index 0 into `$q` index 0, **so another $smallPhrase index[0] will be putted together.**

Comment: You can only push items into arrays. What do you get if you do `var_dump($q[$i]);` before your `array_push()`? Is it an array? Please show us what all those variables, like `$q` and `$smallPhrase` actually contains and what the expected result should look like. It's very unclear what you're trying to do atm.

Comment: I assume you want to push the array `$smallPhrase` to the array `$q` keeping the `index` from the array `$smallPhrase`, right?

Comment: Where did you define `$q` variable and what's the type you assigned? I think you need to define `$q = array();` OR `$q = [];` just before `for` loop and that should do the job.

Comment: expected result = 

$q[0] = $smallPhrase[0][0],$smallPhrase[0][1];
$q[1] = $smallPhrase[1][0],$smallPhrase[1][1];
$q[2] = $smallPhrase[2][0],$smallPhrase[2][1];`

Answer (score 0):

> Edited as per your latest comment

```
$q = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count($smallPhrase); $i++) {
    if (empty($q[$i])) {
        $q[$i] = [];
    }
    array_push($q[$i], ...$smallPhrase[$i]);
}
print_r($q);
```

Comment: I assume you want to push the array $smallPhrase to the array $q keeping the index from the array $smallPhrase < -- perhaps similiar like this

Comment: @fitrafadilana Could you please post the structure of `$smallPhrase` array?

Comment: array(35) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "terima kasih"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "40"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "kemudian"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "20"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "membangun"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "20"
  }
}

actualy this $smallPhrase is under loop also, so the structure's data will be replaced in next loop. so I want keep $smallPhrase index[0] into $q index[0] so on..